# Convert uintmax_t into string c

Tags: c

How to convert uintmax_t into string in C?

Comment: I think you just did it when you typed in your question. Or, are you referring to a *value* of type **uintmax_t**?  In that case, I do believe that `sprintf(3)` or `printf(3)` will be all you need...

Comment: Got solved thanks. Using sprintf

Comment: but how? given that, generally, uintmax_t is a typedef to an underlying type, which would be in some way implementation specific, and %i, %l, %ll etc refer to the underlying types, how can you sprintf a uintmax_t and be sure that it will work correctly on a difference C compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use sprintf to convert to a string. For a type such as uintmax_t , the [inttypes.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/inttypes.h.html) header contains printf conversion specifiers for these types.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   char str[64];
   uintmax_t i = 123456;
   sprintf(str,"Value is %" PRIuMAX "\n",i);
   puts(str);
   return 0;
}
```